# awk syntax and illegal statement error

Tags: awk

I'm getting syntax error for below line. Not sure what is the syntax error.

```
bash-3.2$ awk -F"|" '{ if ($4 != "N.A." && $29 =="1") printf("%s|testfile\n", $4) >> "out1.txt" else if ($4 != "N.A." &&  $29 =="2A") printf("%s|testfile\n", $4) >> "out2.txt" }' infile
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1
```

Comment: It is a good practice to let us know your OS details, you could follow Ed's suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using old, broken awk (/bin/awk on Solaris). On Solaris use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk.

Comment: Getting error when i use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk. 
`/usr/xpg4/bin/awk: syntax error  Context is:
>>>     intf("%s|testfile\n", $4) >> "out1.txt" else       <<<`

Comment: Thanks. This helped.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're just missing `;` after `"out1.txt"`

Comment: Thanks. This helped.